# How to add images as subitems in ListView?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I am  currently working on a standard windows mobile application. It is 
required that we use a ListView, but with images in the sub items.

We need a List View with 3 columns and three rows. I want to show 9 icons on form.

How to add images as subitems in ListView?

I can use picture box but i don't have any event to navigate from one image to another image.

How can I handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support for adding images as subitems in the ListView. If you know that there will always be exactly 3x3 images, why use a ListView? You can simply lay out 9 PictureBox controls on the form and load the icons into them.

Comment: Presumably he wants to have a ListView that shows 9 items at a time on screen, but has a scroll bar to show more if there are more than 9 items.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in a standard ListView use owner-drawing.

Set the `OwnerDraw` property of the ListView to `true`, handle the `DrawColumnHeader` and `DrawItem` events and set `e.Handled` to `true`, and handle the `DrawSubItem` event and draw the correct images.

**EDIT: The .Net Compact Framework does not support owner drawing, so this technique cannot be used.**

Comment: The CF ListView cannot be owner-drawn.  It doesn't support overriding any of the drawing functions.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/bk_custlistview.aspx) article. Although it's written for the full .NET Framework, it might also work for the Compact Framework (I have not tested it myself, but [NMCUSTOMDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931603.aspx) seems to be supported by Win CE).

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/481668-listview-subitems-image-index
Read out this article, it will help you.